How to use OAuth2 on Wildix API
I would like use Wildix API for see the state of my phone for start but I don't know to use authentication.
I had an 403 and 401 error when I try login as me on subdomain.wildixin.com.
I tried to put my token in setting of my script but I have an 401 error.
I replaced my identifiers with xxx.
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Wildix\Integrations\Client;

$config = [
    'host' => 'https://xxx.wildixin.com/',
    'app_id' => 'xxx',
    'secret_key' => 'xxx',
    'app_name' => 'xxx',
];

$client = new Client($config, []);

$options = [
    'params' => [],
    'body' => [],
    'headers' => []
];

$response = $client->get('api/v1/PBX/settings/CallQueues/', $options);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
    'status_code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
    'headers' => $response->getHeaders(),
    'body' => json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents())
]);

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>




Are you really supposed to set an Authorization header yourself? I'd expect that the client automatically sets that, based on the config you passed in? In the basic examples under https://github.com/Wildix/s2s-client-php, I don't see the Authorization header getting passed manually.

seeing that you have done 80+% of the example give here: https://github.com/Wildix/s2s-client-php, you might need to share more details, because we cannot know what you have behind api/v1/PBX/settings/CallQueues/, which can be the cause for this 401

@Luuk by deleting the authorization header I now have a 401 error (before I had a 403 error with the authorization header)
